# Is it necessary to use try/catch when testing callbacks with Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am running a set of tests with Jest 29.7.0 and Node.js 20.10.0, and need to test some callback functions.

The **Callbacks** section of the [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks) explains how to test callback code and gives the following example:

```
test('the data is peanut butter', done => {
  function callback(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      done(error);
      return;
    }
    try {
      expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
      done();
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  }

  fetchData(callback);
});
```

The following explanation of this code states that the `expect` function must be executed inside a `try` block, otherwise the `done` callback is never called in case of the verification failure, and the test will fail with a timeout instead of the actual verification error.

But if I modify this test and remove the try/catch, I still see the correct error message if `expect` fails the test.

```
import { fetchData } from "./testutils";

test('the data is peanut butter', done => {
    function callback(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            done(error);
            return;
        }

        expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
        done();
    }
  
    fetchData(callback);
});
```

This is my `fetchData` function:

```
export function fetchData(callback) {
    callback(undefined, 'strawberry jam');
}
```

And the correct error message (no timeout here):

```
  ● the data is peanut butter
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "peanut butter"
    Received: "strawberry jam"

       8 |         }
       9 |
    > 10 |         expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
         |                      ^
      11 |         done();
      12 |     }
      13 |
```

If I google this topic, I see both kinds of examples - with try/catch and without it. Is this documentation entry misleading/outdated? Or are there nuances not covered in the document and I should expect my tests without try/catch to misbehave in some situations?

Comment: Even if you must implement a callback-based API, you can trivially [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal) it for much simpler testing. Your examples here only work because what you're testing is actually synchronous - `setTimeout(() => callback(...))` and you'll see the test times out instead of properly failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it's necessary to use the `try`/`catch` to ensure `done` is called when testing asynchronous code via callbacks.

---

The documentation is neither misleading nor outdated. You're getting misleading results because your `fetchData` implementation is actually *synchronous*. Make a simple change:

```
function fetchData(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(undefined, 'strawberry jam'));
}
```

and you'll see that, while the assertion's error message is still visible, the test *times out* rather than failing correctly:

```
 FAIL  ./demo.test.js (5.193 s)
  ✕ the data is peanut butter (5002 ms)

  ● the data is peanut butter

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "peanut butter"
    Received: "strawberry jam"

       9 |       return;
      10 |     }
    > 11 |     expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
         |                  ^
      12 |     done();
      13 |     try {
      14 |     } catch (error) {

      at toBe (demo.test.js:11:18)
      at Immediate.callback (demo.test.js:2:22)

  ● the data is peanut butter

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test while waiting for `done()` to be called.
    Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."

      3 | }
      4 |
    > 5 | test('the data is peanut butter', done => {
        | ^
      6 |   function callback(error, data) {
      7 |     if (error) {
      8 |       done(error);

      at Object.test (demo.test.js:5:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.221 s, estimated 6 s
```

The failing assertion `expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');` still throws an error, but that's now outside the synchronous part of the test - it's logged out, but does **not** end the test. Without the `try`/`catch` around it, `done()` is never reached, so the test eventually (5,000ms by default) times out.

---

*With* the `try`/`catch` in place the test correctly fails whether or not `fetchData` is actually asynchronous, but it's very verbose. Here's how to actually test the implementation; using [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal) to turn `fetchData` into a promise that either rejects with `error` or resolves with `data`:

```
import { promisify } from "node:util":

import { fetchData } from "./testutils";

test('the data is peanut butter', async () => {
  await expect(promisify(fetchData)()).resolves.toEqual('peanut butter');
});
```

```
 FAIL  ./demo.test.js
  ✕ the data is peanut butter (3 ms)

  ● the data is peanut butter

    expect(received).resolves.toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: "peanut butter"
    Received: "strawberry jam"

       6 |
       7 | test('the data is peanut butter', async () => {
    >  8 |   await expect(promisify(fetchData)()).resolves.toEqual('peanut butter');
         |                                                 ^
       9 | });
      10 |

      at Object.toEqual (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:166:22)
      at Object.toEqual (demo.test.js:8:49)
```

Even if your consumers require a callback-based API, you can wrap it in a promise-based one to substantially simplify the tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jonrsharpe for the detailed answer and the promisify reference.