Why is this test not failing?
The auth_token property is a string, but I have set it to be Number in order to make it fail.
But it doesn't. Test is passed, though it outlines the token as red, but not failing. why?
I have tried this:
describe('Login customer endpoint', () => {
    it('should return response code of 200 if the user credentials are correct', async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axiosI.post('customer/login', correctCredentialsPayload);
            expect(response.status).toBe(200);
            expect(response.data).toEqual([
                {
                    auth_token: expect.any(Number)
                }
            ])

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message)
        }
    })
});


How can it fail? You catch the error.

To go beyond what @jonrsharpe said, expects throw an error if they are not satisfied, you're catching the error, so it says nothing is wrong. Just remove the try/catch

In testing like this, don't catch exceptions unless you're expecting an exception. Test failures are propagated via the exception handling mechanism.

@tadman don't catch exceptions even if you are expecting one; use toThrow (and .rejects with promises - https://stackoverflow.com/q/78097080/3001761).

@jonrsharpe Thanks for clarifying. Those do catch, but are far more selective and are the correct way of doing it.
